# SQL Add Columns a unique hash

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a 60.000 users.
I Want to create a new colums a user table.
This column has to be a default value. But it must be unique hash. How can i do that.

When new record, this colums create automaticly hash.

Comment: Please provide some sample data to show what you really want.  For instance, a unique hash of what?  And, you could also explain why you need this.

Comment: X user : 1a2b3c4d (32 character hash)
Y User : 5a6b7c8d (Y user doesn't get a X user hash.)

Facebook Contest. Facebook App will be communicate with this hash and username.

Comment: Why not just use an auto-incremented id and pass that to the Facebook contest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `uuid()` function to generate a unique hash. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support function calls as default values, but this can be worked around by using a trigger:

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD COLUMN hash varchar(37);

CREATE TRIGGER users_hash_tr
BEFORE INSERT ON users 
FOR EACH ROW
SET new.hash = uuid();
```